# Reference for problems without efficient algorithm (in polynomial time)

Tags: reference-request, logic, computer-science, computational-complexity

I'm writing paper and need your help in finding some famous (or not so famous) problems without efficient algorithm, but from **logic or computer science.**
So far, I have:

-Boolean satisfiability problem

-decision problem that asks whether a certain string s belongs to the language of a certain context-sensitive grammar G (its PSPACE-complete)

-problem whether a regular expression with exponentiation  denotes all strings over its alphabet (exponential time)

Are there any other more or less famous problems that I could put in paper and write about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Some examples:**

- You could start with any well-known NP-hard problem (that includes NP-complete problems too, as well as [PSPACE-complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PSPACE-complete_problems), etc.).
- Many equivalence-related algorithms for automatons and logic formulas, for example

  - equivalence for deterministic push-down automatons;
  - [see also second-order logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-order_logic#Relation_to_computational_complexity);
  - logics like ATL, LTL or CTL, etc. have variants which are hard, try [this search](https://www.google.com/search?q=2-exptime).
- Some [type inference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_inference) algorithms, e.g. for [rank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_%28type_theory%29#Higher-ranked_polymorphism)-2 types (ranks 3 or higher are undecidable) or for [kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kind_%28type_theory%29)-2 types (kinds 3 or higher are also undecidable).
- Many games, like [go](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_game), lead to hard problems, try [this search](https://www.google.com/search?q=go%20is%20pspace-hard).

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 1):

Oh, there are plenty of famous and important NP-hard problems. Here's the [first list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_NP-complete_problems) from a Google search. IMO the most important ones in practical applications are Bin Packing, Travelling Salesman, and Integer Programming problems, although many other ones are important as well.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting.  Any sorting on a list of $n$ elements is a polynomial problem.

Comment: He's asking for problems for which there do not exist polynomial-time algorithms.